# I cant print the value inside of the disabled textbox = Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

So after making a change in the my profile I wanted to print the new value but it's not printing.

Here's my script

```
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='root']/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]")
print(name.text)
```

and I tried this too

```
name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//body/div[@id='root']/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]")))
print(name.text)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
print(name.get_attribute('value'))
```

Simply print the attribute value from the tag retrieved.

Comment: I have a question so I tried to update all the text fields (refer to image above)  and I wanted to print the new value, during the execution of my script i can see the text field is being updated however as soon the scrip execute the save button all the value from the text field back to its original value like what's on the image above.